# Bold fonts in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get the both the textLabel and the detailTextLabel fonts on my UITableViewCell to be bold. I easy got the textLabel to be bold like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *titleString = [managedObject valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:titleString];
    [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = string;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

However when I try to make the detailTextLabel bold like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *titleString = [managedObject valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:titleString];
    [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = string;

    NSString *subtitleString = [managedObject valueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:subtitleString];
    [string2 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kSubFontSize] range:NSMakeRange(0, string2.length)];
    cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = string2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

This crashes the app with a SIGABRT error.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Which line of code causes the crash? What's the full error message? Make sure none of the values are `nil` or out of range.

Comment: The error comes from the line were I allocate string2

Comment: And did you verify that `subtitleString` isn't `nil`?

Comment: yes via nslog it is exactly what I expect it to be. If I comment out the line where I allocate string2 and replace all the other 'string2' with 'string' I get the desired result just with the wrong string. So maybe the solution is to change the actual of string of 'string' (poor naming now)

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `[managedObject valueForKey:@"subtitle"];` is really an `NSString` and not some other object?

Comment: oh... it is __NSCFString

Comment: That's fine. That's the internal implementation for an `NSString`. You need to provide more details about the error. You seem to be doing it correctly but without more info there isn't much else to go on.

Comment: well you're right in that it must be a problem with [managedObject valueForKey:@"subtitle"] because if I swap both to @"title" it works perfectly. I will edit the question to include a screen shot of the entire error. Thank you for your input

Comment: OK, the image you posted clearly indicates that `subtitleString` is `nil` just as I asked about in my 1st two comments.

Answer (score 2):

- Pertaining to your question in title "Bold fonts in UITableView cell"
- To bold the Table Cell texts, you can achieve in a easy way like below.

  ```
  [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:...];
  [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:...];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To change the text to bold, keeping everything else the same (font, color, ...):

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[cell.textLabel.font.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold]
                                            size:cell.textLabel.font.pointSize];
```

ditto for cell.detailTextLabel.font

Answer (score 0):

I have try the same code in my project, but it work well.
I think you can try to check 'titleString' and 'subtitleString'.
if the two variant is nil in some cell, the code will crash in NSMutableAttributedString init message.